# Versioning small changes in larger REST API

Tags: rest, versioning

I have an internal REST API that has the following properties:

1. It has a relatively large surface (many entities, most of which support all standard verbs)
2. It will evolve slowly and locally (mostly minor changes to individual entities)

I have read some REST versioning strategies, but I do not clearly see how they apply here.

If I use version-in-URL, then when `v2` first appears, it would have just one entity/some verbs in it. The clients will be using `v2` for one entity, `v1` for other, and later maybe `v3` for yet another. That is unless I copy/redirect the whole surface on each change, but that can get me to `v10` quickly just because of 10 unrelated changes in different locations.

If I use version-in-content-type the problems are pretty similar (but I do not think version-in-content-type covers all potential changes so I wasn't planning to do that anyway).

Is there a common approach to evolving the API in this case?

Comment: Create a new major version only for breaking changes

Comment: Of course, but it is quite likely only a single thing in API will get a breaking change at a time. So if 'endpoint' X had a breaking change, what does it mean for the versioning of 'endpoint' Y? Does it immediately move up to `v2` as well? Or only after its own breaking change?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin What solution did you end up with?

Comment: @GoloRoden for now I just version per item, so different parts in the API may have different latest versions — which is confusing but does not seem to be a huge issue otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply :-))